# Accessing android backups on Google from Linux

Tags: linux, backup, android

From time to time, my Android phone makes backups to Google. I know that these backups are made, because I once had to restore some of it. So, I can restore the backups from Google on the Android devices.

However, I would like to access the backups from a Linux system. I have not found anything that could allow me to access the backups. Is this possible? Did I miss some documentation?

I can mount the Google drive on my Linux system with the ocam-fuse, but there doesn't seem to be a backup on that drive.

Comment: Please, tell us which the version and distro Linux.

Comment: I'm not interested in specific linux distro's. My main system is slackware 14.2 (current), but is there's anything working on Ubuntu, Fedora or any of the others, that is fine by me too.

Comment: Related: [Does Google Takeout contain Android Backup for my devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/224427/218526)

Comment: I had not seen that one. So, the answer seems "no, it is not possible".